# Find real roots of equation $ x^5-5x^2+2 = 0 $

Tags: polynomials

Find all real roots of equation $ x^5 - 5x^2 + 2 = 0 $.
I have a solution to this problem (It's not long but tricky) but I don't like it.
I put hint for this tricky solution:

> At the beginning we want to change it into product. It's not by chance that 
>  $ x^{\textit{5}}-\textit{5}x^{\underline{2}} + \underline{2} $ 
> (five-five, two-two repetition)

But it's only my interpretation (heuristic) of first equations. If it's not clear what I mean:

> $ x^5-5x^2+2 = (x^5-x^4-x^3) + (x^4-x^3-x^2) + 2(x^3-x^2-x) - 2(x^2-x-1) = ... = (x^2-x-1)(x^3+x^2+2x-2) $

Second hint:

> We want to solve $ x^3+x^2+2x-2=0 $. 
>  Substitution $ y = x + \frac{1}{3} $

At end:

> $$y^3-\frac{5}{3}y-\frac{70}{27}=0$$.
>  
>  Substitution $$ y = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} (z-\frac{1}{z}) $$ which leads to
>
>  $$z^3 - \frac{1}{z^3} = \frac{14}{\sqrt{5}} $$

*Added after edition*

> How to understand this implication.
>  If $$z^3-\frac{1}{z^3} = \frac{14}{\sqrt{5}}$$ then
>  $$z - \frac{1}{z} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{7+\sqrt{69}}{\sqrt{5}}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{7+\sqrt{69}}}  $$

Answer

> $$ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\quad \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\quad \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} \left ( \sqrt[3]{\frac{7+\sqrt{69}}{\sqrt{5}}} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{7+\sqrt{69}}}  \right ) - \frac{1}{3}$$

Questions

1. Nice solution for this problem?
2. In this type problems only tricks can lead to a solution? (this is magic for me)

**I would like to apologize for naive questions.** But for me it is important to understand substitutions I wrote in hideboxes. Could you please explain this in way that i could see mathematical reasoning, not tricks?

Comment: Polynomials of fifth degree can't be solved in general using only radicals. There are ways to solve them using hypergeometric functions ... I think Felix Klein has a paper on that topic.

Comment: Write $x^5-5x^2+2=(x^2+ax+b)(x^3+cx^2+dx+e)$, multiply out, set coefficients of like powers of $x$ equal to get 5 equations for the five unknowns $a,b,c,d,e$. Simplify by using integrality of the unknowns, e.g., $be=2$ implies $b=2$, $e=1$ or $b=-2$, $e=-1$ or $b=1$, $e=2$ or $b=-1$, $e=-2$. With some perseverance, you find $a,b,c,d,e$ that work, and from there the rest is routine. No magic.

Comment: Thank you. First step is now clear for me.  I now understand that $y(x)$ transformation is about disappearing $ x^2 $. But what about third step $$ y = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} (z-\frac{1}{z}) $$. What idea comes with it?

Comment: @pablo: See [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).